# Which alternatives is there to compile WAV Loops to SWFs?

Tags: flash, audio, build-process, embed, continuous

So far, when I need to embed sound assets in a game, I've always had to bring them in a Flash project's library (a new FLA), setup their properties (linkage / classname, sound quality settings), and then publish this file so I can use it in my main project file, as follow:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/audio/audio.swf#music_track_01")]
public static const MUSIC_TRACK_01:Class;
```

This process is the only way I know of that makes the cleanest, seamless, best "**loopable**" tracks without any **gap** between each playbacks.

So my question is, is there other tools that can automate this task? Auto-compile a bunch of **WAVs** to one common **SWF** sound file?

I've once seen a company using a tool that had their own script-file that would convert *each individual WAV* sounds to *individual SWF* files - all sharing the same linkagename "SWFSound", but (my best educated guess) probably were unique because each one came from their own `ApplicationDomain` from the SWF they were compiled in. But too many files, in my opinion!

If something exists out there, it may be a deciding factor to go with it, or to roll my own script to achieve the same thing (and would likely be a *Windows-only* solution :P)

Answer (score 0):

http://etcs.ru/pre/WAVPlayer/srcview/ This is the one that I know (it generates SWF with PCM data extracted from WAV files - I believe you chosen WAV because of it, otherwise there are few tools that can create SWFs with MP3 data. This is written in AS3, so you could make it an AIR application - not very useful though if you want to run it during the build as it will start the runtime, but as the worst case - should work.

It wouldn't be a problem to rewrite the code in C# for example to make it into Windows executable, basically all it does is just copying data from one file to another + adds some headers.